# Multiple Conditional Classes in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Using Ruby and HAML, is there a shorter way to represent this logic:

```
%tr{class: "#{'success' if admin.approved?} #{'warning' unless admin.approved?}"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use a helper method. I don't recall if you can use ternaries but if you can, also an option.

Comment: Hey @DaveNewton congratz for the 100k reputation milestone! And yes you can actually use ternaries in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify the logic using a ternary statement (one line if/else):

```
%tr{class: admin.approved? ? 'success' : 'warning'}
```

Or you could move the logic to a helper.  For example, create a helper method in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def admin_row_class(admin)
  admin.approved? ? 'success' : 'warning'
end
```

Then use the helper in your view:

```
%tr{class: admin_row_class(admin)}
```

Comment: perfect, thank you! For non-boolean operations or more than 2 results, I guess you just suggest helpers?

Comment: Yes, helpers are the way to go if the logic gets more complicated.

Comment: Helpers are definitely the way to go! I found a useful gem that implements a general version of the helper approach called  [`css-class-string`](https://github.com/nLight/css-class-string). This is how I've been handling conditional CSS classes in my recent projects. I wrote about it [here](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/a-cleaner-way-to-set-multiple-conditional-css-classes-for-link-to.html?utm_source=stackoverflow). Hope that helps!